# How do i only show the latest post from the local user?

Tags: python, django

I have called the latest post but i want the post shown to be related to whoever is using the website

```
calculation = [Math.objects.latest('date')]
calc = getattr([Math.objects.latest('date')][0], 'calculation')
```

```
class Math(models.Model):
calculation = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    get_latest_by = 'date'
```

When switching computer and using running the server again the latest post was still there. Does this happen because `python manage.py runserver` can't tell by IP?

My biggest issue would be if when deployed, the latest post anyone has posted will be shown.

For context i will be using this site for computations which is why they need to be personalised.

Comment: How are you filtering the user? How does your `Math` model look like? Please use [markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to use `getattr` there, anyway.

Comment: Please post the `Math` model too.

Answer (score 1):

django's request attribute has a `user` attribute which can be called using `request.user`. So if your `Math` model looks like

```py
class Math(models.Model):
  calculation = models.DecimalField()
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='calculations')
  date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Where `User` refers to django's `auth.User` model. Now, you can approach this problem two ways. The first one would be to filter by user first and then get the latest like

```py
calculation = Math.objects.filter(user=request.user).latest('date')[0].calculation
```

The other one would be calling the related name directly from `request.user` like

```py
calculations = request.user.calculations.latest('date')[0].calculation
```

Comment: okay, and will this still work for users that are not logged in?